# Get values from check boxes using id or name passed through function

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```
function checkSelect(field_id)
{
    var oParent = document.getElementById(field_id);
    alert(oParent);

    var aElements = oParent.getElementsByTagName('input');
    alert(aElements);   

    var c_value = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++)
    {
        if (aElements[i].type == 'checkbox') 
        {
            if(aElements[i].checked )
            {
                c_value=aElements[i].checked.value;
                alert(c_value);
            }
        }
    }

    //alert(c_value);   
}
```

The code i have searched from here. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I want to get the values of checkboxes by it's fieldname or fieldid passed through function. Javascript is not getting the value "fieldid" as the name of checkbox causes an error. If I give the hardcoded value then it works like function given below.

```
function checkSelect()
{
    var bool=false;
    var field=document.countryManagementForm.country_ids;

    var length=1;
    if(field.length==null)
    {
    //alert("yes");
    }
    else
    {
    ///alert("No");
    length=field.length;
    }




    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(field[i].checked == true)
        {
            bool=true;
        }
    }

    if(!bool)
    {
        alert("Please select atleast one country");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {

        return true;


    }

}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the code is at least syntactically correct. It depends on your HTML. Is the ID you pass the one of the checkbox? If so, the function will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a javascript framework for this. It's a breeze to do what you want to do:

For ID:

```
$('#id').val();
```

For names:

```
$('[name="name"]').val();
```

[Jquery](http://jquery.com/) and the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
c_value=aElements[i].checked.value;
```

to

```
c_value=aElements[i].value;
```

and try it again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `country_ids` is the name of your checkbox inputs. If so, you can replace this line

```
var aElements = oParent.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

by

```
var aElements = document.getElementsByName(field_id);
```

and ignore the lines above it. Call your function as `checkSelect('country_ids')`